# Redux/ImmutableJS Nested States + Big-o Complexity of Immutable Collections

Tags: typescript, redux, immutability, ngrx, immutable-collections

I'm trying to get my head around Immutability for my first Redux (NGRX/Store) project.  Avoiding state mutation has proved extremely painful, and after battling with Object.assign({}) and state mutation errors, I've discovered Immutable.JS.  Which is making things much easier.

Lets say I have a Financial Trading Application, it needs to display a collection of Bars on the chart when loaded.  A couple of times per second, the last bar needs to be updated based on live price information and every so often a new bar will be added.

And this all needs to happen for {1-n} financial instruments (EURUSD/GBPJPY/Gold/Oil etc.).  So I've come up with this model for this part of my app:

```
export interface CandleState {
  LastCompletedCandle : Candle;
  InProgressCandle : Candle;
  LastTick:Offer;
  ClosedCandles:immutable.List<Candle>;
};

export interface AllCandleState {
   instruments: immutable.Map<string, CandleState>
}
```

You'll notice that I have an Immutable Map which contains an Immutable List.  So my first question is:  Is there any point to doing 'immutability within immutability' like this? Since calling

```
instruments.set("EURUSD", { [my new state] })
```

is effectively returning a whole new state and therefore I am not clear if I need to have nested immutability like this.... I do want to be able to subscribe to changes on the ClosedCandles list; will making this immutable allow things to observe that for changes directly?  Or are these things only detected from the 'top' level.

I guess my next question is: do I need to worry about this at all.  I've got it into my head that changing an immutable collection is a very expensive operation.  If I do list.push or map.set  what is actually happening under the hood.  Am I copying every single item in the entire array or map into to a brand new array/map one by one - every time I need to change something in an immutable collection?  Or am I just changing a reference or something?

I wish there was some published info on the Big-Oh Complexity of immutable collections it would make it easy to understand how these things will perform, but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any point to doing 'immutability within immutability' like this?

For most parts, the very primitive answer is: No. - For change-detection purposes it doesn't matter if an object is immutable - however it does help you to enforce the concept of always creating a new object and never mutate an existing state outside the store(and even in the reducer itself).

> I do want to be able to subscribe to changes on the ClosedCandles
>   list; will making this immutable allow things to observe that for
>   changes directly? Or are these things only detected from the 'top'
>   level.

Yes and no. Observing the change directly can be achieved by setting up a stream that directly selects `instruments.ClosedCandles` - however this is no special case for immutability, this could be done with or without immutability.

Now for the immutability and the *top down*-part: It will always be the case, that when you want to alter something n levels down an object, that every parent of your altered object (up to the root) has to be recreated, simply because the parent cannot be altered if immutable thus you cannot just set a new reference.

Example:

```
root                <-- to enable changing the map1, you have to recreate the root, since it is immutable
|--map1             <-- to enable changing the set2, you have to recreate this map, since it is immutable
|  |--set1          <-- untouched, the "new version" of map1 will reference the same "set1"
|  \--set2          <-- to enable changing the attribute2, you have to recreate this set, since it is also immutable
|     |--attribute1 <-- untouched, the "new version" of set2 will just have the same reference on this object as the "old version"
|     \--attribute2 <-- you want to alter this attribute
|
|--map2             <-- untouched, the "new version" of root will reference the same "map2"
\--map3             <-- untouched, the "new version" of root will reference the same "map3"
```

> I guess my next question is: do I need to worry about this at all.
>   I've got it into my head that changing an immutable collection is a
>   very expensive operation. If I do list.push or map.set what is
>   actually happening under the hood. Am I copying every single item in
>   the entire array or map into to a brand new array/map one by one -
>   every time I need to change something in an immutable collection? Or
>   am I just changing a reference or something?

This primarily depends on how you use immutables, most libraries optimize this and also wrap away this stuff so you don't have to worry about it. As for the performance: In most cases it won't be a big deal, most mutations only change small parts of the state and the rest of the state will just consist of new references and usually no new objects are created.

However in performance-critical cases you can use a strategy where you only use immutables for development- and test-builds to ensure your application works correctly and for production-builds you deactivate immutability to optimize even the last bit of performance.